# A pythonic way to append new values to a dict?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

Let's consider:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Then, we create a dictionary as:

```
vnf_dict = dict([(key, [None]) for key in (x)])
```

This gives us:

```
vnf_dict: {1: [None], 2: [None], 3: [None], 4: [None], 5: [None], 6: [None], 7: [None]}
```

Now I update the values for each key with the following function, previously deleting 'None' in case exists.

```
def add_value(value, dictionary):
    if None in dictionary[value]:
        dictionary[value] = []
        dictionary[value].append(['Hello'])
    else:
        dictionary[value].append(['By'])
    return dictionary
```

Hence obtaining:

```
print(add_value(1, vnf_dict))
print(add_value(1, vnf_dict))


vnf_dict: {1: [['Hello']], 2: [None], 3: [None], 4: [None], 5: [None], 6: [None], 7: [None]}
vnf_dict: {1: [['Hello'], ['By']], 2: [None], 3: [None], 4: [None], 5: [None], 6: [None], 7: [None]}
```

Is there a faster/Pythonic way to implement all the above?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

```py
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> vnf = defaultdict(list)
>>> vnf[1].append(["Hello"])
>>> vnf[1].append(["Bye"])
>>> vnf[0].append(["Greetings"])
>>> vnf
defaultdict(list, {1: [['Hello'], ['Bye']], 0: [['Greetings']]})
```

Comment: The dictionary keys need to be created from an external list. Dictionary values need to be initialize as 'None'. Finally, when a value is added for the first time, the actual value 'None' must be delete it.

Comment: @krm76 If you stay so strictly to the original design I am hard pressed to find anything Pythonic, since it sounds highly unpythonic to me.

Answer (score 0):

Condition 1 :

If there is a dictionary(d1). We want to omit that and place another dictionary(d2)

For eg :

d1 = v1

d2 = v2

Now, we will d1 = v2.

```
dct = {
    "name": "Sou",
    "quality": {"type1": "dishonest", "type2": "devil"},
    "marks": [{"english": 1}, {"math": 2}],
}

input = {
    "name": "Roopa",
    "type1": "beautiful",
    "type2": "charming",
    "english": 100,
    "math": 500
}

print(dct)
print(".....")

def change1(d,input):
    if isinstance(d,list) : 
        for x in d : change1(x,input)
    elif isinstance(d,dict):
        for k,v in d.items():
            if isinstance(v,(dict,list)):
                change1(v, input)
            else: d[k] = input.get(k,v)
                
change1(dct, input)
print(dct)    

"""
{'name': 'Roopa',
 'quality': {'type1': 'beautiful', 'type2': 'charming'}, 
 'marks': [{'english': 100}, {'math': 500}]}
 
"""
```